# Any way to change the path from our API System to our Main System

Tags: php, laravel

We have 2 different system that's hosted to 2 different server. Let's call them API and CRM. The system we have on API obviously is all APIs and the CRM is our main system. So we also have this website where we can create a data in our Database.

I'm having trouble in finding a way to put the uploaded file from API to CRM server. The code is `$upload->path = $folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$date_append.$filename;` and it looks like this `"path/to/api/[date]-filename"`

since `$folder = storage_path('uploads');`

So how do I make it `path/to/CRM/[date]-filename` instead of API where it's originally created?

Comment: Unless both systems share the server you will need to move the files by using ssh or FTP. Otherwise, the best and most correct approach is the one commented by @Ahmed Hassan, using any Cloud storage

Answer (score 2):

if your API server is public and you don't mind using it as hosting for the image then you can use it in the CRM like this ex: [https://apiserverdomain.com/path/to/CRM/[date]-filename](https://apiserverdomain.com/path/to/CRM/%5Bdate%5D-filename).

but the best practice is to use Cloud Storage (like AWS S3 or Google Cloud or even FTP) and display the URL in your CRM from the Cloud Storage directly

I hope it's helpful

Comment: I'll try these solutions. Thanks brother!

Comment: @LaurenzMelosantos you are most welcome, good luck